# Separar en una clase distinta metodos de lectura y escritura JSON

Tags: java, json, clase, try-catch

estoy haciendo un inventario usando JSON como base de datos, lo que quiero hacer es separar el metodo que uso para leer y escribir en otra clase, así es como lo tengo para registrar un usuario y funciona correctamente:

```
public void REGISTRAR_USUARIO() {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jrr = new JSONArray();
        JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();

        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("UserData.json");
            jrr = (JSONArray) jp.parse(file);
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e);
        }

        PEDIR_DATOS();

        obj.put("Username", nombre);
        obj.put("Password", contraseña);

        jrr.add(obj);

        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("UserData.json");
            file.write(jrr.toJSONString());
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

pero ahora quiero separar ese metodo try catch en otra clase y llamar a esa clase para no tener que usar todo eso en todo el codigo, lo forma que trate de separarlo en otra clase fue asi, pero no me funciona:

```
public class DAO {

    private final JSONArray jrr = new JSONArray();
    private final JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();

    public void ESCRIBIR_DATOS(JSONArray jrr) {
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("UserData.json");
            file.write(jrr.toJSONString());
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void LEER_DATOS(JSONArray jrr, JSONParser jp) {
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("UserData.json");
            jrr = (JSONArray) jp.parse(file);
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu json es un array, puedes hacer uso de un ciclo for para recorrerlo y leer los datos

```
 public void REGISTRAR_USUARIO() {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject ();
        JSONArray jrr = new JSONArray ();

        PEDIR_DATOS();
        
        obj.put("Username", nombre);
        obj.put("Password", contraseña);
        jrr.add(obj);
        try {
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("UserData.json");
            file.write(jrr.toJSONString());
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Ha ocurrido un error: " + e);
        }
    }

 public void LEER_DATOS(){

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse (new FileReader ("UserData.json"));
            JSONArray json = (JSONArray) obj;

            for (Object o : json) {

                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) o;
                String Username = object.get ("Username").toString ();
                String Password = object.get ("Password").toString ();
                System.out.println ("Nombre: " + Username);
                System.out.println ("Contraseña: " + Password);

            }
        }catch (IOException |ParseException e){
            System.err.println ("ERROR "+ e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Disculpa, no entendí muy bien tu solución.

Comment: fragmente tu código en dos la primera parte genera el json y la otra lee el json ,solo te recalque que al estar usando un jsonarray,al momento de leerlo puedes hacer uso de un for u otro ciclo